# Why does a positive definite matrix with a repeated eigenvalue have infinitely many square roots?

Tags: linear-algebra

So, if we consider a positive definite matrix $A$, (meaning that $A$ is self-adjoint $(Ax,x) > 0$ and also that $A$ has strictly positive eigenvalues) we see right away that since it is self adjoint, and has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $h_{i}$, that it has a uniquely determined positive square root.  We see this, since for the basis
\begin{align}
\{h_{1},...,h_{n}\}
\end{align}
each $x$ can be written as
\begin{align}
x &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n}c_{i}h_{i} \\
\Rightarrow Hx &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}Hh_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}\lambda_{i}h_{i}.
\end{align}

We let $\sqrt{H}x$ be represented by
\begin{align}
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}\sqrt{\lambda_{i}}h_{i}.
\end{align}
where we take $\sqrt{\lambda_{i}}$ to be the positive square root of $\lambda_{i}$. Naturally, one sees that this is the unique positive definite square root, and that there are $2^{n}$ possible square roots, however, I keep reading that if $A$ has a repeated eigenvalue there are infinitely many square roots.  Why is this?

Please note by square root I mean $S$ such that $S^{2} = A$.

Comment: Hint: how many reflections (with respect to a line passing through the origin) are there in a plane?

Comment: where did you read this ? do you think that the identity matrix $I_2$ has infinitely many square routs ?

Comment: @OmranKouba Read the first two lines [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Properties). This also answers the question of the OP since one can treat the repeated eigenvalues as an identity submatrix times a positive eigenvalue.

Comment: @DRich, could you please write the matrix equation that you want your "square root" to satisfy? The two most common usages are $C C^T = A$ or actual $C^2 = A.$

Comment: As a remark, please note that while $A$ has infinitely many *Hermitian* square roots (and hence infinitely many square roots), only one of them is positive definite.

Comment: Sorry Will, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

In case you mean ["square root"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Square_roots_of_positive_operators) as $C C^T = A:$

Suppose $A = \lambda^2 I$ two by two,

$$ C \; = \;  \lambda
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  \cos \theta  &  \sin \theta  \\
   -\sin \theta   &  \cos \theta  
\end{array} 
  \right)  ,
  $$
which is to say that a rotated basis of a two-dimensional eigenspace is being used.

Comment: In this sense, actually any SPD matrix would have infinitely many "square roots" as $A=CC^T=(CQ)(CQ)^T$ for any orthogonal $Q$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel, that tends to support the idea that the question is about $C^2 = A.$ I see that he edited that in, about 12 minutes before i write this.