# Number of square roots of a positive self-adjoint matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm going through Chpt 10 of Peter Lax's Linear Algebra and its Applications, and I'm a bit confused by one of the solutions to an exercise.  The question is "how many square roots are there of a positive mapping?".

The way this concept is introduced is by looking at the orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, where an arbitrary vector $x$ can be written as
$$x=\sum x_jh_j$$
Then, for corresponding eigenvalues $a_j$, we have
$$Hx=\sum x_ja_jh_j$$
He then defines the square root as
$$\sqrt{H}x=\sum x_j\sqrt{a_j}h_j$$
His answer for the case of distinct eigenvalues is that there are $2^n$ square roots, where $n$ is the number of distinct eigenvalues.  This part I can understand, although it seems like the convention is to take the positive square roots for each $a_j$, I think the question is how many possible combinations are there.

Where I don't understand is why if one non-zero eigenvalue has a multiplicity greater than one, $H$ has infinitely many square roots.  Surely it would just be $2^{n-m}\cdot m$, where $m$ is the multiplicity of the eigenvalue?

I've seen the answer here ([Why does a positive definite matrix with a repeated eigenvalue have infinitely many square roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755268/why-does-a-positive-definite-matrix-with-a-repeated-eigenvalue-have-infinitely-m)), but I think it's still missing some steps from repeated eigenvalues to infinitely many square roots.  I think the comment about $(\sqrt{H})^2=H$ is probably closest, but I think an algebraic explanation would be the most convincing, as opposed to specific examples.

Answer (score 3):

You're not requiring the square root to be positive itself, so it's not unique, especially if an eigenspace has dimension $n>1$.  The identity matrix for $n>1$ has a continuum of square roots.  For example, in $n=2$, for any $x,y,z\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, take the matrix
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
z &x-iy\\
x+iy & -z
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $M^\dagger=M$, $\operatorname{tr}(M)=0$, $\det(M) = -x^2-y^2-z^2=-1$.  So $M$ is unitarily diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\pm 1$.  This implies that $M^2=1_{2\times 2}$.  And you have a whole sphere-worth of these - a continuum.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the positive definite matrix $H$ has an eigenvalue with multiplicity $> 1$.  Take an orthonormal basis $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ of eigenvectors of $H$ corresponding to eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$, where for convenience $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$.  Thus $\sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{\lambda_j} v_j v_j^*$ is a square root of $H$.  But so is
$$ \sqrt{\lambda_1} (\cos(\theta) v_1 v_1^* + \sin(\theta) v_1 v_2^* +\sin(\theta) v_2 v_1^* - \cos(\theta) v_2 v_2^*) + \sum_{j=3}^n \sqrt{\lambda_j} v_j v_j^* $$
for any $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Would this be equivalent to saying that once there is a multiplicity of >1, there is a subspace with dimension >1 of vectors which can be substituted into the sum, so there are infinite possible "substitutions"?  Maybe connecting it back to the Spectral theorem, where the eigenvectors (genuine or generalised) would be what I'm trying to explain in effect?