# Examples of operator equations on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let T be a positive compact operator on a Hilbert space then we know that an operator equation $X^2 = T$ have a solution.

Im confused since we have a result which says that a compact operator $T \geq 0$ have an unique operator $X$ which is compact, positive and $X^2 = T$. How there can be a compact operator $T\geq 0$ which have uncountable many solutions?

The result where im refering, its from John B. Conway, A course in functional analysis, Graduate Texts in Mathematics 96, Springer 1990.: [image]

What would be an example of an operator $T$ which have uncountable many solutions?

Comment: $T=0$. I leave it to you to find solutions.

Comment: Are you assuming anything about $X$ here? If not, then I would suggest $T = I$, on the Hilbert space $\Bbb{R}^2$, and $X$ be a reflection in any line through the origin.

Comment: Well atleast we cant assume that $X^2$ is positive and compact because then the solution would be unique.

Comment: $X^2$ is $T$, which is given... Is there any assumption on $X$? Please edit the question, if it changes, comments are often ignored (and/or not shown by default).

Comment: There is a unique *positive* solution and uncountably many solutions if you drop the requirement of positivity.  Even in dimension $2$, there is a submanifold of solutions so it's uncountable.  Of these, only one is positive.

Comment: ah i see @ChadK i understand now the amount of solutions. unfortunately im not familiar with manifolds yet...

Comment: @voroshilov: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4831075/1168056)

Comment: nice @ChadK, so you can pick basically a polynomial which have n roots and write in a way as in your answer and you obtain n solutions for the operator?